# Add a function to a program, and call that function from the command line in the function

Tags: c, shell, unix

I have to add a custom function which shows currently running foreground and background processes launched by this shell.  How do I define and call that function from the shell's command line?

```
#include "smallsh.h" /*include file for example*/

/*program buffers and work pointers*/
static char inpbuf[MAXBUF], tokbuf[2*MAXBUF],
*ptr = inpbuf, *tok = tokbuf;

userin(p) /*print prompt and read a line*/
char *p;
{

  int c, count;

  /*initialization for later routines*/
  ptr = inpbuf;
  tok = tokbuf;

  /*display prompt*/
  printf("%s ",p);

  for(count = 0;;)
  {
    if((c = getchar()) == EOF)
      return(EOF);

    if(count<MAXBUF)
      inpbuf[count++] = c;

    if(c == '\n' && count <MAXBUF)
    {
      inpbuf[count] = '\0';
      return(count);
    }

    /*if line too long restart*/
    if(c == '\n')
    {
      printf("smallsh:input line too long\n");
      count = 0;
      printf("%s",p);
    }
  }
}

gettok(outptr) /*get token and place into tokbuf*/
char **outptr;
{
  int type;

*outptr = tok;

/*strip white space*/
for(;*ptr == ' ' || *ptr == '\t'; ptr++)
  ;

*tok++ = *ptr;

  switch(*ptr++)
  {
    case '\n':
      type = EOL; break;
    case '&':
      type = AMPERSAND; break;
    case ';':
      type = SEMICOLON; break;
    case '#':
      type = POUND; break;
    default:
      type = ARG;
      while(inarg(*ptr))
        *tok++ = *ptr++;
  }

*tok++ = '\0';
return(type);
}

static char special[]=
{' ', '\t', '&', ':', '\n', '\0'};

inarg(c) /*are we in an ordinary argument*/
char c;
{
  char *wrk;

  for(wrk = special;*wrk != '\0';wrk++)
    if(c == *wrk)
      return(0);

    return(1);
}

#include "smallsh.h"

procline() /*process input line*/
{
  char *arg[MAXARG+1]; /*pointer array for runcommand*/
  int toktype; /*type of token in command*/
  int narg; /*number of arguments so far*/
  int type; /*FOREGROUND or BACKGROUND*/

  for(narg = 0;;)
  {
    /*loop FOREVER*/

    /*take action according to token type*/

    switch(toktype = gettok(&arg[narg]))
    {
      case ARG:

      if(narg<MAXARG)
        narg++;
      break;

      case EOL:
      case SEMICOLON:
      case AMPERSAND:
      case POUND:

        type = (toktype == AMPERSAND) ?
        BACKGROUND : FOREGROUND;

        if(narg!=0)
        {
          arg[narg] = NULL;
          runcommand(arg, type);
        }

        if((toktype == EOL)||(toktype=POUND))
          return;

        narg = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
}


#include "smallsh.h"

/*execute a command with optional wait*/
runcommand(cline,where)
char **cline;
int where;
{
  int pid, exitstat, ret;

  if((pid = fork()) <0)
  {
    perror("smallsh");
    return(-1);
  }

  if(pid == 0)
  {
    /*child*/
    execvp(*cline, cline);
    perror(*cline);
    exit(127);
  }

  /*code for parent*/
  /*if background process print pid and exit*/

  if(where == BACKGROUND)
  {
    printf("[Process id %d]\n", pid);
    return(0);
  }

  /*wait until process pid exists*/

  while( (ret=wait(&exitstat)) != pid && ret != -1)
    ;

  return(ret == -1 ? -1 : exitstat);
}

#include "smallsh.h"

char *prompt = "Command>"; /*prompt*/

main()
{
  while(userin(prompt) != EOF)
    procline();
}
```

To try to call a function, Inside of runcommand, before the code for the child process, I tried to add another if statement saying `if(cline == "dowork"){dowork();}`, and tried putting in similar lines elsewhere, but nothing like that works.

Comment: Can you add some more clarification as to what you want to achieve? Perhaps sketch it out in pseudocode.

Comment: When asking any question, it's good to have a complete description of the problem.  Just posting the code isn't sufficient.  When asking a homework question (thanks for tagging it!), you should write out what you think the problem is as well as how you've tried to solve it.  Then reduce the code you post to the specific area you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is C, `cline == "dowork"` will not do what you want.  You need to change that to:

```
if (strcmp(cline, "dowork") == 0)
{
    ...
}
```

If you wanted your shell to also handle "DOWORK", "DoWork", etc. you can replace `strcmp` with `strcasecmp`.

**Update**: since you have `char **cline`, you need to change that to:

```
if (strcmp(*cline, "dowork") == 0)
```

Also, you should be compiling with warnings - if you do that the compile will have told you you had a type mismatch here.

Comment: Where exactly would this go? I placed it like so at the front of runcommand:
runcommand(cline,where)
char **cline;
int where;
{
int pid, exitstat, ret;

if(strcasecmp(cline, "dowork")==0)
{
   dowork(proclist);
}

if((pid = fork()) <0)
{
   perror("smallsh");
   return(-1);
}
And it simply printed another line of the command prompt

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a list of internal commands like:

"`cd`" "`ls`" and check the user input against this list, if an internal command is regonized simply call the function that implements the internal command.

EDIT: I was assuming you're implementing a small shell like application.

Comment: eah, it is a small shell like application, but I'm supposed to define a command/function that provides additional functionality and then call it from the shell

Comment: @user336291 you should add the requirements to your question